# How to build the GCC cross compiler for Cross Linux From Scratch (CLFS) for Beagleboard?

Tags: embedded, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

Currently I try to build a embedded Linux from scratch with the instructions from [Cross Linux from Scratch](http://cross-lfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/index.html).

Everything worked fine until I tried to compile the GCC Cross-Compiler. I want to build the Linux for the Beagleboard-xM... So I choosed the following settings:

```
export CLFS_ABI="aapcs-linux"
export CLFS_HOST="x86_64-cross-linux-gnu"
export CLFS_TARGET="armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi"
export CLFS_ARCH="arm"
export CLFS_ENDIAN="little"
export CLFS_ARM_ARCH="armv7"
export CLFS_ARM_MODE="arm"
export CLFS_FLOAT="hard"
export CLFS_FPU="neon"
```

No as soon as I try to run the instructions on this [page](http://cross-lfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/cross-tools/gcc-static.html) the command `make all-gcc all-target-libgcc` runs into an error.

```
checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-gcc...  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
```

and the `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc/config.log` looks like this:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Runtime Library configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-4.6.0/libgcc/configure --cache-file=./config.cache --with-cross-host=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu --prefix=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-sysroot=/mnt/clfs --disable-nls --disable-shared --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-threads --disable-multilib --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv7 --with-mode=arm --with-float=hard --with-fpu=neon --enable-languages=c,lto --program-transform-name=s&^&armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-& --disable-option-checking --with-target-subdir=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --build=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu --host=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --target=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --srcdir=../../../gcc-4.6.0/libgcc

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = virtualUbuntu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.2.0-31-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1742: creating cache ./config.cache
configure:1903: checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
configure:1916: result: no
configure:1964: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2032: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2048: checking for gawk
configure:2075: result: gawk
configure:2095: checking build system type
configure:2109: result: x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
configure:2129: checking host system type
configure:2142: result: armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
configure:2245: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-ar
configure:2272: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar
configure:2337: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
configure:2364: result: armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
configure:2429: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-nm
configure:2456: result: /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm
configure:2521: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-ranlib
configure:2548: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib
configure:2613: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-strip
configure:2640: result: /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip
configure:2702: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2706: result: yes
configure:2723: checking for armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-gcc
configure:2750: result:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   
configure:3019: checking for C compiler version
configure:3028:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    --version >&5
xgcc (GCC) 4.6.0
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3039: $? = 0
configure:3028:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -v >&5
Reading specs from /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/specs
COLLECT_GCC=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/lto-wrapper
Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.0/configure --prefix=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --build=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu --target=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi --with-sysroot=/mnt/clfs --disable-nls --disable-shared --with-mpfr=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-gmp=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --with-mpc=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools --without-headers --with-newlib --disable-decimal-float --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-threads --enable-languages=c --disable-multilib --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv7 --with-mode=arm --with-float=hard --with-fpu=neon
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.6.0 (GCC) 
configure:3039: $? = 0
configure:3028:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3039: $? = 1
configure:3028:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3039: $? = 1
configure:3055:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:1:0: error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
configure:3058: $? = 1
configure:3246: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3268:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:1:0: error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
configure:3272: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3286: error: in `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/libgcc':
configure:3289: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-g -O2'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_host=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AR=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
ac_cv_prog_LIPO=armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo
ac_cv_prog_NM=/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm
ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ar'
AWK='gawk'
CC=' /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include   '
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
NM='/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/nm'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Runtime Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Runtime Library 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libgcc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/strip'
ac_ct_CC=''
asm_hidden_op=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-cross-linux-gnu'
build_alias='x86_64-cross-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-cross-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-cross-linux-gnu'
build_vendor='cross'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
decimal_float=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_decimal_float='no'
enable_shared='no'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_parts=''
fixed_point=''
host='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_alias='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_cpu='armv7a'
host_noncanonical='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
host_os='linux-uclibceabi'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libgcc_topdir='../../../gcc-4.6.0/libgcc/..'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mnt/clfs/cross-tools'
program_transform_name='s&^&armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
set_have_cc_tls=''
set_use_emutls=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
slibdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(host_noncanonical)/lib'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
target_noncanonical='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
target_subdir='armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi'
tmake_file=''
toolexecdir='$(exec_prefix)/$(target_noncanonical)'
toolexeclibdir='$(toolexecdir)/lib'
vis_hide=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"

configure: exit 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `CLFS_ARCH="thumb"` work any better? I don't know why arm wouldn't work though, AFAIK uClibc supports both.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I change the CLFS_ARCH to thumb it works just fine... but is there a way to use the arm?

Comment: look at this:
`configure:3039: $? = 0
configure:3028:  /mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/bin/ -B/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/lib/ -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/include -isystem /mnt/clfs/cross-tools/armv7a-unknown-linux-uclibceabi/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.`
it trys to find the xgcc version with `-V` but on my ubuntu only the `-v` works...

Comment: Consider using [Buildroot](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/c4e4110d22332fd35d629259ccdfe9b934c9c633/board/beaglebone) instead of CLFS since it is fully automated from source, and very widely used and reliable. Or study what Buildroot is doing, and copy it.

Answer (score 3):

The errors are likely from a wrong combination of build variables.

The [CLFS Build Variable](http://cross-lfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/cross-tools/variables.html) page has detailed explanation on the best combinations of variable settings for different architectures.

[Similar configure script problems](http://linux.error-exception.org/article/1004842/CLFS:+Building+cross-gcc+4.7.2+under+Ubuntu+12.04.1) has been solved by changing the `CLFS_ARCH` variable to `thumb`

For another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741060/building-cross-gcc-4-7-2-under-ubuntu-12-04-1) BeagleBoard configure script error, the following set of variables seem to do the trick: `ARMv7-A Thumb-2 - Little-Endian, Soft-Float, GLIBC`

If you have been using CLFS 1.x.x, consider using [CLFS 2.x.x](http://trac.cross-lfs.org/wiki/news#AnnouncingCLFS2.0.0Release) for a cleaner build approach, with [updated documentation](http://cross-lfs.org/files/BOOK/2.0.0/).

The best place to discuss CLFS issues is in the [clfs-support mailing list](http://lists.cross-lfs.org/listinfo.cgi/clfs-support-cross-lfs.org), try asking your question there for further insights.