# CLFS for ARMv7 neon

Tags: embedded, gcc, arm, cross-compilation, assembly

I am following [CLFS book (GIT-20140613-arm version)](http://clfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/index.html), and I have a issue when building GCC with armv7 and neon combination. [Target info here](http://pastebin.com/TrynDk2q).

My host is a clean Debian 8 with gawk, build-essential, texinfo and libncurses5-dev packages. More details can [be found here](http://pastebin.com/nCDaX0Bx).

I made [this patch](http://pastebin.com/4u58jCdg) to build binutils with gcc-4.9.

Following the instructions, when it comes to compile GCC for the very first time it claims not to be possible to these arm combination.

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/clfs/sources/gcc-build/arm-linux-musleabihf/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

On `config.log` we can see:

```
conftest.c:1:0: error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
```

I linked the [complete error here](http://pastebin.com/PTRYQ625).

In my research I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49752/clfs-building-gcc-cross-compiler) which sounds to be the same, but the OP was following a very old version of CLFS book, I managed to surpass this bug by appending `--with-mode=thumb` to `./configure`, but then
musl fails:

```
arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc -std=c99 -nostdinc -ffreestanding -fexcess-precision=standard -frounding-math -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -I./arch/arm -I./src/internal -I./include -Os -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=pointer-sign -Werror=pointer-arith -fno-stack-protector -c -o crt/crt1.o crt/arm/crt1.s
crt/arm/crt1.s: Assembler messages:
crt/arm/crt1.s:6: Error: only lo regs allowed with immediate -- `mov fp,#0'
crt/arm/crt1.s:7: Error: only lo regs allowed with immediate -- `mov lr,#0'
crt/arm/crt1.s:8: Error: Thumb does not support this addressing mode -- `ldr a2,[sp],#4'
crt/arm/crt1.s:11: Error: lo register required -- `str fp,[sp,#-4]!'
crt/arm/crt1.s:12: Error: Thumb does not support this addressing mode -- `str a1,[sp,#-4]!'
crt/arm/crt1.s:13: Error: Thumb does not support this addressing mode -- `str a4,[sp,#-4]!'
Makefile:112: recipe for target 'crt/crt1.o' failed
make: *** [crt/crt1.o] Error 1
```

I have also [tried `vfp` and `vfpv3` combinations](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.clfs.support/2303), and I have also [tried to use Linaro GCC](http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter7/) instead of [GNU one](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ARMv7), no luck at all.

Once I made this book successfully till the end for Raspberry Pi One (hard, vfp and armv6), but I am in trouble with the Beaglebone combination.

What am I missing? Is my environment correct? If so, what could I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For BeagleBone Black, the correct environment settings is `armv7-a`, as we can see [here](http://beagleboard.org/linux) and [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/BeagleBone_Black), and we need to pick up the kernel settings from [here](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux) with `bb.org_defconfig`, and use headers from [here](https://github.com/sabotage-linux/kernel-headers), and patches for `gcc` from [here](https://github.com/GregorR/musl-cross/tree/master/patches), and remember to build final `gcc` with `--disable-libsanitizer`.

I used the following command before build `musl`:

```
sed -i 's/\/dev\/null\/utmp/\/var\/run\/utmp/g;s/\/dev\/null\/wtmp/\/var\/log\/wtmp/g' include/paths.h include/utmp.h
```

And the following before build `busybox` to solve `wtmp` issues:

```
sed -i 's/\(CONFIG_\)\(.*\)\(INETD\)\(.*\)=y/# \1\2\3\4 is not set/g;s/\(CONFIG_IFPLUGD\|CONFIG_ASH_HELP\|CONFIG_FEATURE_VERBOSE\|CONFIG_UEVENT\)=y/# \1 is not set/' .config
sed -i '/utmpx\.h/,/endif/s/__UCLIBC__/LIBBB_H/' include/libbb.h
```

Complete package list:

```
wget -cO bootscripts-embedded-HEAD.tar.gz -c 'http://git.clfs.org/?p=bootscripts-embedded.git;a=snapshot;h=HEAD;sf=tgz'
wget -cO gcc-5.2.0-musl-1.patch 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GregorR/musl-cross/master/patches/gcc-5.2.0-musl.diff'
wget -c \
    'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.25.1.tar.bz2' \
    'http://busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.24.0.tar.bz2' \
    'ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2' \
    'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.1.3.tar.xz' \
    'http://sethwklein.net/iana-etc-2.30.tar.bz2' \
    'http://ftp.barfooze.de/pub/sabotage/tarballs/kernel-headers-3.12.6-5.tar.xz' \
    'https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/archive/4.1.tar.gz' \
    'ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/u-boot/u-boot-2015.10.tar.bz2' \
    'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc/mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz' \
    'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-3.1.3.tar.xz' \
    'http://www.musl-libc.org/releases/musl-1.1.9.tar.gz' \
    'https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/releases/dropbear-2015.68.tar.bz2' \
    'http://www.red-bean.com/~bos/netplug/netplug-1.2.9.2.tar.bz2' \
    'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.9.tar.gz' \
    'http://patches.clfs.org/embedded-dev/iana-etc-2.30-update-2.patch' \
    'http://patches.clfs.org/embedded-dev/netplug-1.2.9.2-fixes-1.patch' \
    'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz'
```

That solves all issues.