# Building kernel for BeagleBone Black lead me hdmi problems

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, arm, cross-compilation, lfs

I have successfully followed [CLFS book to build RPi and BBB embedded systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232809/56001). In RPi case the bootloader did not give me problems with device tree.

Some years ago I would have to patch Torvalds' Kernel to [build BBB one](http://beagleboard.org/source), nowadays we have it already patched on [github](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/).

I can see my kernel working over UART cable, but it does not show on HDMI screen, the original system on eMMC does. I have tried versions 4.4 and 4.1 but the result is the same.

I also built my own [U-Boot](http://pastebin.com/RFAgFbBq), I build the kernel with `am335x-boneblack.dtb`, and I have tried to build [the Bone-Black-HDMI cape](https://github.com/jadonk/cape-firmware/raw/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/cape-boneblack-hdmi-00A0.dts) and even after successfully installed on `/sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots`, the screen remains empty.

I have also tried to build the kernel with `CONFIG_DEBUG_LL`, `CONFIG_ARM_APPENDED_DTB`, `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_AM33XXUART1`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_OMAP2PLUS_UART`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_INCLUDE=debug/omap2plus.S` and any combination of them.

How can I enable HDMI on raw BBB kernel? Preferably during the boot, because the way I did it was on `/etc/rc.d/startup`, it would take a while till show on screen, although it has not even worked.

Comment: I am passing in my kernel parameters this in my Lamobo R1. "sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60"

Comment: I have tried video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e and now disp.screen0_output_mode, same result

Comment: I tried `video=omapfb:mode:1280x720@60` and there is no `/sys/class/graphics/fb0` directory, only `fbcon`, and I added `fb          root:video 0666` to `mdev.conf` with no reaction.